# Regex to match URLs generating partially invalid output

Tags: ruby, regex, url

I am trying to use the following regex code in my Ruby application to match HTTP links, but it generates invalid output, appending a period, sometimes a period and a word, behind the link which, when tested on the web, becomes invalid.

```
URL_PATTERN  = Regexp.new %r{http://[\w/.%-]+}i
<input>.to_s.scan( URL_PATTERN ).uniq
```

Is there some problem with the above code for scanning the links?

Code from the app:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'twitter'

RECORD_LIMIT = 100
URL_PATTERN  = Regexp.new %r{http://[\w/.%-]+}i

def usage
  warn "Usage: ruby #{File.basename $0} <hashtag>"  
  exit 64
end

# Ensure that the hashtag has a hash symbol. This makes the leading '#'
# optional, which avoids the need to quote or escape it on the command line.
def format_hashtag(hashtag)  
  (hashtag.scan(/^#/).empty?) ? "##{hashtag}" : hashtag
end

# Return a sorted list of unique URLs found in the list of tweets.
def uniq_urls(tweets)  
  tweets.map(&:text).grep( %r{http://}i ).to_s.scan( URL_PATTERN ).uniq
end

def search(hashtag)  
  Twitter.search(hashtag, rpp: RECORD_LIMIT, result_type: 'recent')
end

if __FILE__ == $0 usage unless ARGV.size >= 1  
hashtag = format_hashtag(ARGV[0]) 
tweets = search(hashtag) 
puts uniq_urls(tweets)
end
```

Comment: Provide test input strings, actual results and expected results.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Actually i am trying to extract Http links from twitter. So please help me in that context.

Comment: Sergio's comment still stands: what are cases when this provides invalid output?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I am trying to understand the working of [url extractor app](https://github.com/CodeGnome/twitter_url_extractor), where this code is mentioned.

Comment: Can't help unless you can provide examples of it misbehaving

Comment: @FrederickCheung, ok.. when i try to run this particular app, e.g. ruby Foo.rb #rubyonrails, it returns multiple http links some of which are appended with a dot(.) or with an alphabet.(a-z). Such links if copied and pasted on the navigation bar are found to be invalid.

Comment: actual example please. The devil with these things is almost always in the details

Comment: @FrederickCheung, you can now check the code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Please have a look onto the code

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

People post bad links all the time. Links are also subject to bit-rot.

#### The Likely Answer

Have you verified the Tweets manually? Are you sure that the original Tweet doesn't contain a malformed URL? If someone posts:

> http://foo.Any more toast?

then you're certainly going to get an invalid result because the regex requires whitespace around the URL. If you want to prune invalid results, then you will need to use a link-checker that can handle redirects to validate each link you find.

#### Author's Disclaimer

The code you're posting is mine, from [CodeGnome/twitter_url_extractor](https://github.com/CodeGnome/twitter_url_extractor). I deliberately left out link-checking, because I was interested in extracting URLs, not validating them.

"It works for me; your mileage may vary."℠

Comment: it's really nice to have you on answer

Comment: Yes, I checked that original tweet doesn't contain a malformed URL and if I remove that extra dot(.) or alphabet the link works fine. But anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: +1 Note OP can alleviate the issue somewhat by excluding trailing periods, and, generally speaking, smartening up the regex a bit. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10789288/990363) for a start, [Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)’s the limit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your regex will include a trailing period, as you are indiscriminately checking for an arbitrary sequence of word characters, slashes, percent signs, hyphens (aka “minus”) **and periods**. This will catch a trailing period that is in fact punctuation when the URL is at the end of a sentence, and, if people omit the space following the period, anything after that – [as CodeGnome correctly stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788022/990363). You can partly alleviate this issue  by excluding trailing punctuation like this (note this will still catch punctuation directly followed by non-URL stuff):

```
http://\w+(?:[./%-]\w+)+$
```

However, this will still miss a large proportion of existing URLs and catch a lot of invalid stuff: [URLs are quite complex beasts](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/). If you want a perfect match, John Gruber posted [a regex](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) that matches about anything that is used as a URL today, not just http(s) ones. For a closer match of a large crop of web-only URLs, including the HTTPS variant, making sure you have a well formed domain at the start, and catching queries and fragment identifiers, the regex should look something like this:

```
https?://[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+(?:/[\w-]+)*(?:(?:[./%?=&#-]\w+)+)?
```

– this will still catch invalid stuff, and exclude quite some existing URLs (and an even larger proportion of valid URLs – see the RFC I linked to above), but it will get you closer.

Comment: Also note you don’t need to do `Regexp.new %r{<stuff>}` – `%r{}` is the literal regex declaration form, meaning it returns a Regexp object. Oh, and Ruby code does not end with `end` – `end` denotes the end of a block (function, condition, proc), not script end.

Comment: +1 for the link to Gruber's regex; I found it useful. However, folks should note that while it handles trailing punctuation and URIs embedded in quotes, run-on sentences can't be easily distinguished from valid URLs. Oftentimes good programming is about knowing when a solution is "good enough" to address the problem domain. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, why not use Ruby's [URI.extract](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract)? It's bundled with Ruby.

From the documentation:

```
Synopsis

URI::extract(str[, schemes][,&blk])

Args

str     String to extract URIs from.
schemes Limit URI matching to a specific schemes.

Description

Extracts URIs from a string. If block given, iterates through all matched URIs. Returns nil if block given or array with matches.
Usage

require "uri"

URI.extract("text here http://foo.example.org/bla and here mailto:test@example.com and here also.")
# => ["http://foo.example.com/bla", "mailto:test@example.com"]
```

If you only want HTTP URLs:

```
[3] (pry) main: 0> URI.extract("text here http://foo.example.org/bla and here mailto:test@example.com and here also.", %w[http])
=> ["http://foo.example.org/bla"]
```

Comment: URI.extract doesn't seem to handle trailing punctuation - for example if you have the url in brackets, the matched url will include the trailing bracket

Comment: URI.extract uses a regex to determine what is a URL/URI. If trailing characters are valid in URIs it will capture them. The same would occur with periods and other valid characters. It isn't designed to be used against markup or templates where you'd typically find brackets or braces, but general text which usually delimits URIs with whitespace. For markup it's more sensible to use a parser, like Nokogiri, to retrieve the URI. No matter what, it's expected that you'd know your source and anticipate the possible problems.